# Ruby on Rails - Getting parameter values as hash onside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i get the values passed in the URL `check/1?Answers[1]=2&Answers[7]=3&Answers[6]=4&Answers[4]=0` in controller

`@answers = params[:Answers]` ?

How can i convert `@answers` to the format `{1 => 2, 7 => 3, 6 => 4, 4 => 0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that in all String you can convert is in Integer

```
answers  = params[:Answer].inject({}) do |answers, line|
  answers[line[0].to_i] = line[1].to_i
  answers
end
```